# ¿Cómo cambiar valor de la propiedad de una clase por su nombre?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, viewmodel

tengo implementado un `ViewModel` pero necesito cambiar los valores de unas propiedades en función de su nombre mas exactamente sumarle uno

**FormViewModel**

```
class FormViewModel : ViewModel(), Observable {
    ...
    var c2=""
        @Bindable get
        set(v){
            field=v
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.c2)
        }
    var c3=""
        @Bindable get
        set(v){
            field=v
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.c3)
        }
    var c4=""
        @Bindable get
        set(v){
            field=v
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.c4)
        }
    var c5=""
        @Bindable get
        set(v){
            field=v
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.c5)
        }
    var c6=""
        @Bindable get
        set(v){
            field=v
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.c6)
        }
    ...
    fun onMore(num:Int){
        this["c"+num]=this["c"+num].toInt()+1//esto no sirve pero es lo que quiero
    }
}
```

como podría hacer esto he leído algo de la delegación de clases pero no se como implementarlo en un `ViewModel`

### **Motivo**

---

tengo dos botones por cada uno los campos y solo quiero asignarles una funcion de click a todos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

deben sumar o restar 1 según el botón que presionen

**capture_fragment**

```xml
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/contpor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="Portadores"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/contpdc">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/textC2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/textC3"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textC3"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/labc2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@{@string/c(`2`)}"
                    android:labelFor="@id/editc2"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editc2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                    android:text="@={modelo.c2}"
                    android:background="#eee"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/labc2"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/morec2" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/morec2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:background="#00E676"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_more"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="8dp"
                    android:onClick="@{()->modelo.onMore()}"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/editc2"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/lessc2"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/lessc2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_less"
                    android:background="#FF6E40"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/editc2"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/morec2"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/textC3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/textC5"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/textC2"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/textC4"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/labc3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@{@string/c(`3`)}"
                    android:labelFor="@id/editc3"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editc3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                    android:text="@={modelo.c3}"
                    android:background="#eee"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/labc3"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/morec3" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/morec3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:background="#00E676"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_more"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/editc3"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/lessc3"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/lessc3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_less"
                    android:background="#FF6E40"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/editc3"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/morec3"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
       ...
       </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

si tienen una mejor manera de hacer este diseño les agradecería muchísimo si me dijeran cual

Comment: Se puede hacer con reflexión pero sería bueno que contaras cuál es el problema que quieres resolver con esta "solución" porque estoy seguro que debe haber mejores alternativas.

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem ya coloque mi argumento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución que propones solamente es posible usando reflection, lo cual debe evitarse siempre que sea posible. Una mejor alternativa es tener todos los valores juntos en una colección o array y hacer las operaciones basadas en sus índices

```
val values = Array(5) { "" }

fun onMore(index: Int) {
    val value = values[index].toIntOrNull() ?: 0
    values[index] = (value + 1).toString()
}
```

Si te pierden los índices puedes hacerlo con un map

```
val values = mutableMapOf(
    "c2" to "",
    "c3" to "",
    ...
)

fun onMore(key: String) {
    val value = values[key]?.toIntOrNull() ?: 0
    values[key] = (value + 1).toString()
}
```

De esta forma simplemente debes llamar la función con el nombre de la entrada que quieres aumentar. Por ejemplo `onMore("c2")`.

Si buscas una solución mas moderna podrías crear un componente usando [jetpack compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose). Dentro del componente puedes definir un estado y funciones que lo modifiquen. Esta forma de crear componentes te resultará familiar si has usado algún framework declarativo como react.js, flutter, etc.